# Delete filename from subfolders

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am trying to use a batch file to delete all files of a given name in all sub directories under a sub directory. I basically have a folder that has thousands of folders with GUID names that has a file that needs to be deleted out of each one regularly and I don't want to keep having to do a search and delete.

typical subfolders look like:

```
C:\folder\{000D5D3E-A54D-4B0B-8B03-95AC591CB20A}\
C:\folder\{00DBFD07-3218-4DC2-83CA-27A7D14D782C}\
C:\folder\{00A08715-0811-6142-50AE-82A332EA3A5F}\
...etc
```

and I want to delete:

```
C:\folder\{000D5D3E-A54D-4B0B-8B03-95AC591CB20A}\log.xml
C:\folder\{90DBFD07-3218-4DC2-83CA-27A7D14D782C}\log.xml
C:\folder\{A0A08715-0811-6142-50AE-82A332EA3A5F}\log.xml
...etc
```

This is what I have so far.. but I can't get it to work.. any suggestions?

```
SET _DIR_="C:\FOLDER"
SET _PATTERN_="C:\folder\{*}\log.xml"
C:
CD %_DIR_%
for /r /%f in (%_PATTERN_%) do ECHO "%f"
```

Thanks. Please only reply with ways to do this in a batch file  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

love loops with safe belt:

```
for /d /r "C:\folder" %%i in (*) do if exist "%%~fi\log.xml" echo del "%%~fi\log.xml"
```

Answer (score 3):

***TEST THIS ON A TEST SUBTREE FIRST - IT'S VERY DANGEROUS IF YOUR TYPING IS AS BAD AS MINE**

(Sorry to shout - but you do need to be very, very careful with this one...

Try this command **FIRST**

```
DIR /S c:\FOLDER\log.xml
```

and if that produces a list of the files you want to delete, then

```
DEL /S c:\FOLDER\log.xml
```

will delete them.

Comment: Um I think what the questioner wants is to have the log.xml deleted ONLY from the folder patterns with GUID names.. like c:\FOLDER\{32423... and not just a folder like c:\FOLDER\something\log.xml.

Comment: @Power-Inside -OP stated `Inside all sub directories under a sub directory` but certainly, programmed all `{..}` dirctories. Goes to prove how important it is to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir {*} /s /b') do cd %%i&&del log.xml
```

to use at command line simply replace %%i with %i.
this should delete log.xml from any folder names starting with '{' and ending with '}'

Navigate to the proper directory *first*!